# Simple for loop is taking time to execute in android

Tags: java, android, android-emulator

I have implemented a code in java which has a for loop which varies from 0 to 0x10000 times.
Now i am importing this code into android and running the same code.

Problem if that:
In Core java loop executes with in 2 seconds at max.
But when same loop is being executed in android it is taking 4 minutes (Disgusting)

Please can any one help me out from this, i am pasting my loop for your understanding:

```
   for (int r = 0; r < 0x10000; r++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < password.length; j += 4) {
                long[] key = {0, 0, 0, 0};
                for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                    if (i + j < password.length) {
                       //do something
                    }
                }
                //calling one method.
            }

        }
```

Basically main loop varies upto 64000 times. Please suggest.

Comment: Amazing..... how would you compare int to HEX.

Comment: Yup it does and works

Comment: so what does "//do something" and "//calling one method" actually do? The loop itself should be fast enough. Also have you tried to extract `password.length` to a separate final variable? Should speed up a bit, too.

Comment: Are you running this on emulator?

Comment: I'll wager a guess and say that the emulator is your problem - it is *not* as fast as a real device and you really shouldn't use it for testing if you can help it. Also, if you're replying to someone in a comment please add their name so that they are notified like so: @NandakishoreK

Comment: @Amit Koranne, I've faced similar problems where the emulator is really slow and the real device is not. Try it on an actual device.

Answer (score 0):

May be this can help a little:

```
int maxR = 0x10000;
int passwordLength = password.length;
for (int r = 0; r < maxR; r++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < passwordLength; j += 4) {
        long[] key = {0, 0, 0, 0};
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            if (i + j < passwordLength) {
               //do something
            }
        }
        //calling one method.
    }
}
```

But I think that the thing to optimized is probably the content of your last for loop and the method you call after it...

**[EDIT]** If you don't access to other items of the "key" array than the one at index i, you can do what Joop Eggen suggested:

```
int maxR = 0x10000;
int passwordLength = password.length;
long[] key = {0, 0, 0, 0};
for (int r = 0; r < maxR; r++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < passwordLength; j += 4) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            key[i] = 0;
            if (i + j < passwordLength) {
               //do something
            }
        }
        //calling one method.
    }
}
```

Comment: But Execution in java is fine its taking few seconds. Problem is in android.

Comment: I think it's not due to Android but to your device. Your device has limited resources compared to your computer.

Comment: The answer of Joop Eggen is not correct. It only works when the length of your password is a multiple of 4.

Comment: So I'm sorry but it seems that it's your code inside loops which runs slowly. The first version of @Joop Eggen missed a lot of cases, like his second one it seems

Answer (score 0):

```
long[] key = new long[4];
int incompleteFourer = password.length % 4;
int n = password.length - incompleteFourer ;
for (int r = 0; r < 0x10000; r++) {
   for (int j = 0; j < n; j += 4) {
       for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
           key[i] = 0;
           //do something
        }
        //calling one method.
    }
    if (incompleteFourer != 0) {
        int j = n;;
        //calling one method.
    }
}
```

Memory allocation of `key` only once; assume "do something" only considers `key[i]`.
Index of j to always have full 4 elements; "calling one method" might not handle some of the three last elements.
The last 1 to 3 elements are handled separately.

NetBeans IDE has a nice profiler, and maybe the same bottleneck concerns both loops. At least measure times of indiivual calls on Android; maybe it is a slow Dalvik implementation of some basic function.

Comment: not that bad but a short explanation would be appreciated.... for example: where is the if statement?

Comment: @Joop Eggen (password.length - 4 + 1) this is playing trick to make fast, but it fails to give me right output. Please suggest